# Como abrir uma nova Janela em PySide2?

Tags: python, pyside

Eu estava usando uma função parar abrir as janelas em uma espécie de 'gerente' de janelas.
No topo da class eu deixo o menu = False, e quando ele se torna True na função, é para a janela abrir, mas não sei se desse modo está correto.

Segue o código que chama a janela:

```
    def login(self):
    global menu

    #CHAMAR BANCO DE DADOS DE LOGIN
    u = Users()

    #COLETANDO DADOS
    operador = txt_usuario.text()
    senha = txt_senha.text()
    entrar = u.selectOperador(operador,senha)

    #VERIFICANDO DADOS
    if entrar == 'Operador conectado':
        menu = True
        self.close()
```

Segue o código do 'Gerente' de janelas, que no caso é outro arquivo python feito exclusivamente para isso:

```
import OxMuscle as vl
import sys
import cadastro as c
import menu as m

def carrega_sistema():
    #TENHO IMPRESSÃO QUE O PROBLEMA SEGUE AQUI, JÁ QUE SEMPRE QUE FECHO A JANELA NO "X", AS RESPECTIVAS JANELAS SÃO ABERTAS EM SEGUIDA
    vl.executa()
    menu = m.executa()
    cadastro = c.executa()

    if cadastro:
        c.executa()


    if menu:
        m.executa()

carrega_sistema()

sys.exit(0)
```

Se acharem necessário todos os códigos, por favor, me informem que eu posto aqui

Comment: Já viu este [tutorial](https://www.learnpyqt.com/tutorials/creating-multiple-windows/)?

Comment: Eu vi, mas o objetivo não é abrir uma janela no mesmo arquivo python, e sim abrir uma janela criada em outro arquivo.
Por exemplo:
Estou no OxMuscle.py e lá foi construída uma janela de login, ao clicar em entrar eu quero chamar a Janela que foi criada em menu.py, deu pra entender?